# RDP slower when connecting a Windows 7 Ultimate to Server 2003?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, windows-server-2003, performance

I have a successful RDP connection on Windows XP Professional to Windows Server 2003 at a remote site.
I setup another machine running Windows 7 Ultimate.
although I am able to get connection, comparing the machines side by side, the Windows 7 connection is dog slow.
I have compares that the 2 RDP connections is identical as far as experience etc.
I have run a internet connection speed test which show the 2 computers connect at the same speed to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote Desktop on Windows 7 is leveraging a feature called auto-tuning for TCP/IP. This might be the culprit in your case.

I have had success running the following command to speed things up:

`netsh interface tcp set global autotuninglevel=highlyrestricted`

Comment: Hi Do is just run this in a cmd screen? will it keep the settings when I reboot?

Comment: @Johann Kruger: Yes and yes :)

Answer (score 1):

Silly point to make, but check whether a cabled connection to your network makes a difference to your RDP client's performance.

I have a Windows 7 64-bit box acting as a server, RDP enabled, etc.  Windows XP machines can connect at normal frame-rates over wifi but Windows 7 machines connect at about 1 frame in 10 seconds...

Connecting the Win7 machines directly to my router with a network cable completely cured the issue, so now it seems I have some troubleshooting to do on my wifi network :-)